# Modify / Import the spl-token to my program

Tags: program, spl

I'm looking to make a basic solana program with just some slight modifications from the [spl token program](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library).

Is there an example of importing the spl program and then adding a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPL-Token is a program that is currently used as the token standard on Solana. In order to add additional functionality to the program, you have to either:

1. Extend the token program and wrap the existing instructions with your program's instructions, adding additional functionality
2. Use a new program to manage a PDA built off of the token account and add additional functionality(This is what Metaplex does with NFTs)

You can find an example of wrapping some of the existing SPL-Token instructions with another program in these [program examples](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/mint-2).

It all depends on the functionality you want to add.

There is an upcoming token22 standard that allows [extensions to be added](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions), but the functionality is still set to a few different extensions. The preferred way to add functionality is still listed in the 2 options above.